# pip install pymssql fails in anaconda windows

Tags: python, sql-server, anaconda, pymssql

I want to work with sql server in orange through anaconda.
When installing pymssql I am getting the attached error.
After hours of googling I could not find a solution for anaconda.
Please help!
Thank you
Michael

_mssql.c(266): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sqlfront.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue before.
I would recommend downloading v2 of pymssql: 
    pip install pymssql==2.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Try using: `pip install pymssql` in the Anaconda directory. It worked for me, it is like using conda. 
In my case (Windows 10) I just typed in the following in command line:

```
cd C:/Anaconda3
pip install pymssql
```